# Want to execute every adobe jsx script in folder using a windows batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, adobe

This is what I have. I also want it to wait for each file to finish before moving on to the next. I can't seem to get it to execute the actual command. Can anyone help?

```
for %%G in ("C:\Users\theUser\Documents\Adobe Scripts\t\*.jsx") DO "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe" -run "%%G"
pause
```

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with your code.  Are you getting any error messages?  Run your script from the cmd prompt otherwise it may close on a fatal error and you wont see it.

Comment: I found 2 issues just now. 1 of the jsx files had an error, and it was causing the command to break the loop somehow, and 2 I was getting a "-run" command can not be found.

I've modified as such, but it is still not waiting for one to finish before executing the next.

<code>
for %%G in ("C:\Users\theUser\Documents\Adobe Scripts\t\*.jsx") DO (
 START /WAIT "" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Adobe ExtendScript Toolkit CC\ExtendScript Toolkit.exe" -run "%%G"
)
<code>

Comment: I would assume it is not waiting because the executable launches another process to execute the script and then releases control.  That is my best guess.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I wonder if adobe has some way of sending a wait command.

Comment: Meanwhile 
timeout /10 seems to be enough.

Comment: Yeah, but that kind of sucks.  One option is to call out to a function that launches the script.  Inside the function keep checking tasklist every 2 seconds to see if the script is still running.  If it doesn't find it in the task list then end the loop for checking.  I just don't know what you need to look for in task manager.  I don't have that program installed on my computer.